# Web API with OAuthBearerTokens and WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearer

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin, adal

I'm developing an API with multiple ways to authorize/authenticate the user. Currently I added support to the **Azure Activie Directory**. But it seems like that the **default** OAuth Bearer tokens and the Azure AD doesn't work well together. The problem is that every time a user uses the OAuth Bearer token the **JwtSecurityTokenHandler** used for Azure AD throws an Exception.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: IDX10708:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this
>   string: ... The string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of
>   the form:

Auth setup:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

   app.UseAutofacMiddleware();
   app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
   {
       TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
       RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider(),
       Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
       AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
       AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
       AllowInsecureHttp = true,
   });

   app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
   {
       TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
       },
       Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
       Provider = new Office365OAuthProvider()
   });
}
```

How do I stop the API to auth the user against the Azure AD when using OAuth token?